# Convert Code to Typescript - The Clean Way

Tags: javascript, typescript, coding-style

I'm trying to convert some JS code to typescript (and clean it up in general)...

This is what I currently have:

```
const EVENT_TYPES = ['coffee', 'lunch', ''];

const ALIAS_EVENT_TYPES = {
    cafe        : 'coffee',
    caffe       : 'coffee',
    meal.      : ‘lunch’
};

let TYPES = createTypeDictionary();

function createTypeDictionary() {
    let types : any = {};
        _.each(EVENT_TYPES, function(type) {
          if (type) {
              types[type] = type;
          }
      });
      _.each(ALIAS_EVENT_TYPES, function(type, index) {
          types[index] = type;
      });
    return types;
  }
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a shorter, cleaner way to do this? (I can't get rid of EVENT_TYPES or ALIAS_EVENT_TYPES)
   way to
2. Right now I have "let types : any = {};" -- Is there a better way to specify that types will be a dictionary? Or is any ok?
3. What should the return type of the function be? object?

I guess my general question is - how to I improve this code? Clean it up and better typescript?

Comment: You should almost certainly always use `const` when you aren't going to reassign the variable in question. `let` can be seen as a *warning* that you're going to reassign later.

Comment: `meal. : ‘lunch’` That will cause a syntax error.

Comment: I can't help but notice your "typescript" lacks any types at all, except for the single `any`.

Answer (score 0):

> Clean it up and better typescript?

Use a string union:

```
type EVENT_TYPES = 'coffee' | 'lunch';
```